# Cache information given by compiler during compile time

Tags: c++, c, cpu-cache

In order to check whether AVX or SSE is available, the compiler usually sets **SSE** or **AVX** true. However is there an option, how to receive during compile time the size of the cache?

Edit:
I refrase the question a little bit, since it is not clear enough.

I want information about the cache during compile time. The more the better. I would like to have it for optimization purposes (i.e. cache-blocking,...). In my current task - spatial blocking - the size of the cache is mostly relevant. But the comments bellow rightly asked, which level of cache am i asking for. In addition caches can behave very differrently, if you consider their evicting strategy, size of cache line, amount of levels, how they are shared between cores... The list goes on.

So my general question: How do i recieve any information about the cache during compile time?

For my current task, it would be sufficient to readout `/proc/cpuinfo` and use the cachesize given there. However the general question is far more interesting.

How do i recieve information about the cpu (with focus on its cache) during compile time?

(I am not considering of crosscompiling at all. The code compiled will be run on the SAME machine.)

Comment: which cache ? L1 or L2 or L3 ? or size of cache line ?

Comment: Cache size is not generally part of the ISA, nor of ISA-extensions. Also, cache is characterized by much more than size. Associativity, eviction policy, write-back/write-through, level, number of processors/cores/hardware-threads that share the cache...

Comment: Forgot to mention: d-cache/i-cache/unified cache, virtually/physically indexed/tagged, coherent/non-coherent (and which coherence-protocol if any), interaction with TLB(size, levels, hardware/software-refill), cache-line size.

Comment: What should happen when I take your program compiled on an i7 with 6MB L2 cache and run it on an i5 with 4MB L2 cache?

Comment: @immibis Difficult to answer, either there will be no difference because it is very hard to control an algorithm to this point to match with implementation detais of the cache, or maybe his optimization will be counter productive on other CPUs.

Comment: @hr0m Even if it is not provided by the compiler, you can make decisions in your code at runtime reading caches topology from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/`.

Comment: @amigadev yes i know that i can read it out per hand with a script during compile time or runtime. But that is not the answer to my question. The question remains: Can do compiler do that for me?

Comment: @hr0m Not only with a script, your program itself can read these entries and adapt the algorithm accordingly. I think the only thing that is done by the compiler about the cache is the alignment of functions and loops on the cache line size. Optimization by the compiler and related to a given CPU is about instructions (specific instructions, scheduling, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, no compiler is capable of having such detailed information about a cpu AND making it available to the compiling program. However i have found a [library](https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid), which seems to do exactly that. Sadly again only at runtime. However it is at least a comfortable solution.

(I found it by accident. I was not looking for it :) If you ever look for something, 1) google 2) look [here](https://github.com/jnv/lists))

Comment: Taking a quick look it seems like this library still does everything at runtime

Comment: @vu1p3n0x damn i haven't took a look, you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can compile several versions of your library for various cache sizes and then pick them dynamically. That is the only possible approach for adding cache size info at compile-time.